# Declaring FILE pointers in Cython

Tags: python, cython

How do we declare file pointers in Cython? If I use the following:

```
cdef FILE* f
```

It shows the error "FILE is not a type identifier".

Please suggest any changes.

Comment: a quick search pulled up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356606/pass-file-handle-to-cython-function and the answer contains an example

Answer (score 2):

```
from libc.stdio cimport FILE
```

Definitions here: https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libc/stdio.pxd